# MySQL insert differences values into two tables

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, transactions

i got two tables and my environment transaction is allowed...

Table A - **ID + Name**

Table B - **ID + Value A+ Value B+ IDTable A**

may i know how to write the query to insert value at once ? hope it can be done within single query...just performance is the highest concern.

Comment: Hi, im trying to create a same table as yours how to do so...? can u please put the sql u did... thank you

Comment: @Loshi , The question below this is just the right answer for me =) and that's the code while i just edit a bit on content and what to put ^^

Comment: nope mate i want to create two tables as table1 table 2 to put user details separately and user pw and name separately.. im havn trouble creating two tables as such. that why i wanted to how to creat the tables

Comment: @Loshi, you mean creating two table or insert data to two tables ? this is inserting into two table. if talking of create table the simply write two  CREATE TABLE, done http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language

Comment: how to add the same id to both tables?

Comment: @Loshi another easier way to achieve is make it not to auto generate id, then add the id into both tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query("BEGIN");

$result_1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_a ('name') values ('Chris')");

if( ! $result_1) {
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    die(); // or handle the error however you choose
}

$table_1_id = mysql_insert_id();
$result_2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_b ('value_a', 'value_b', 'table_a_id') values ('v1', 'v2', $table_1_id)");

if( ! $result_2) {
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    die(); // or handle the error however you choose
}

mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: @Spencer No problem. Realised after posting the answer that you didn't specify PHP, but the principals are the same.

Comment: @chris it's okay, No worry =D Since your solution is easy to understand ^^

Comment: @chris , may i ask you a little question ? should i create foreign key for them if i insert value in your way ?

Comment: As a general rule, yes, but it's hard to tell without knowing your database

Comment: i got member table (standard member info eg. username password) and plan to add address table + bio table...what kind of information you need ? please advice... Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can't do insert on different tables with a single query.

```
insert into tableA (name) values ('name');
set @last = last_insert_id();
insert into tableB (valueA,valueB,idtableA) values ('valueA','valueB',@last);
```